# Magento - Declare HTML HEAD tag as dynamic block in LESTI FPC

Tags: magento, lesti-fpc

Very simple question -

In our current configuration , due to Google Analytics and other systems our Magento store integrates with, we need to keep the HTML HEAD tag as dynamic in LESTI FPC .

Would that cause any issues or trouble ?

Do we need to pay attention to anything ?

Regards ,

James

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you should pay any attention to any other things than the fact that the tag is not cached if it should not. IMHO, the google analytics can be cached as it does not change but I am not specialist in analytics issues.

Comment: The analytics tag itself is static , but in order to call it we need to output dynamic data such as cart list for user - which is page independent , also not only GA requires HEAD integration with dynamic data page independent.